# Get text value from div using selenium web driver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this html :

```
<div class="b-datalist__item__subj">
hello
<span class="b-datalist__item__subj__snippet">hello world</span>
</div>
```

And I want to get only **`"hello"`** text, without **`"hello world"`**. I write this code:

```
subject = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'b-datalist__item__subj']")).getText();
```

But in console output I see **`"hellohello world"`**. How can I fix it?

Comment: The <span> is inside the <div>.  You'll want to look at the first child of the DIV to get that particular text node.

Comment: @ChrisSteele Can you fix my xpath, pls?

Comment: Something like `//div[@class = 'b-datalist__item__subj']/text()` will find the text node, I think.

Comment: @ChrisSteele It works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to "subtract" the text inside the `span` from the complete text in the `div`. Something like:

```
String outsideText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div")).getText();
String insideText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span")).getText();
String yourText = outsideText.replace(insideText, "");
```

Adjust the XPaths as necessary for your situation.

Comment: hmm, it's a very nice idea, but can I make it more simple with 1 xpath expression?

Comment: There is no support in XPath for what you are asking.

Comment: No problem. I should amend my comment above, in case anyone quotes me. :p XPath does have several `substring*` methods, most appropriate for your situation is probably http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_2.html#Functions~substring-before . However, these are not available in Selenium; `By.xpath()` implements only methods that return entire XML nodes.

Comment: can use findElement(By.cssSelector("div") though.

Answer (score -1):

use the below as xpath:

```
//div[text()='hello']
```

Comment: I can have diff values in this tag, not only hello